# I get same spams everyday in website even after i delete them

Tags: mysql, wordpress, blogs, spam, spam-prevention

I get new post every day in my wordpress Mysql wp_post table also when i google my site Google Shown me "This site may be hacked." How can i protect these spams permanently. I have to go to Mysql Database everyday to Delete them manually using this code `"DELETE FROM wp_post WHERE Post_status="test"`. because i can only see them in the database. Most of them are Essay writing blogs

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running WordPress, here are two steps you could take to avoid spams.

Steps:

1) Activate akismet. Visit this [link](http://docs.akismet.com/getting-started/activate/) to know more.

2) once logged into your site's dashboard go to -> **Settings** -> **Discussion**.

Then under **Other comment settings** check the checkbox that says **Users must be registered and logged in to comment**. After that save your changes and see if your spams persist.

3) Make sure you don't have any plugin that runs a MySQL insert query. Try disabling all plugins and see the result.

Hope that helps.